# A Widget takes up the whole screen in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a mobile application with Flutter. The home page in the application looks different on the emulator on the computer and different on the phone.

Emulator:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0snM.png)

My phone:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkMbB.jpg)

Why could this be? How can I solve it?

HomePage.dart:

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Ana Sayfa",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            onPressed: () async {
              await userDB.signOut();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Merhaba, ${name.length > 11 ? '${name.substring(0, 12)}...' : name}",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: textColorBlack,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        menuController.index.value = 4;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        color: deepRed,
                      ),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                color: lightRed,
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.warning,
                                  color: textColorWhite,
                                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.055,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03),
                          const Center(
                            child: Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                "Yardıma ihtiyacım var!",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  color: textColorWhite,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_outlined),
                  Text(
                    "Önemli Kaynaklar",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 6),
              StreamBuilder(
                stream: db.collection("blog").snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: lightRed,
                    );
                  } else {
                    final List<Post> data = snapshot.data!.docs
                        .map((e) => Post.fromDocument(e))
                        .toList();
                    final List<Widget> carouselItems =
                        _buildCarouselItems(data.take(3).toList());
                    return data.isEmpty != true
                        ? InkWell(
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              child: CarouselSlider(
                                items: carouselItems,
                                options: CarouselOptions(
                                  height: 150,
                                  viewportFraction: 1,
                                  initialPage: carouselIndex,
                                  enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                                  reverse: true,
                                  autoPlay: true,
                                  autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                                  autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                                      const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                                  autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                                  enlargeCenterPage: false,
                                  enlargeFactor: 0.3,
                                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      carouselIndex = index;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              Get.to(
                                const PostDetailPage(),
                                arguments: data[carouselIndex],
                                transition: Transition.cupertino,
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : Container(
                            height: 150,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            color: backgroundGrey,
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: const [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.newspaper,
                                  size: 60,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5),
                                Text(
                                  "İçerik Bulunamadı",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 26,
                                    color: textColorBlack,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                  }
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_outlined),
                  Text(
                    "Hızlı erişim",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.005),
              Row(
                children: [
                  FastAccessButton(
                    const Icon(Icons.broken_image),
                    "Son Depremler",
                    () {
                      menuController.index.value = 1;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02),
                  FastAccessButton(
                    const Icon(Icons.newspaper),
                    "İçerikler",
                    () {
                      menuController.index.value = 3;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              Row(
                children: [
                  FastAccessButton(
                    const Icon(Icons.people),
                    "Kişilerim",
                    () {
                      menuController.index.value = 2;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02),
                  FastAccessButton(
                    const Icon(Icons.settings),
                    "Ayarlar",
                    () {
                      menuController.index.value = 4;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_outlined),
                  Text(
                    "En son 2 deprem",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18,
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Earthquake>>(
                  future: _quakesFuture,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const SizedBox(
                        width: 150,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              color: lightRed,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          Earthquake item = snapshot.data![index];
                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 75,
                            child: Card(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                              ),
                              elevation: 3,
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text("${item.location} - ${item.time}"),
                                subtitle: Text("Büyüklük: ${item.magnitude}"),
                                trailing: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Get.to(const EarthquakeDetailPage(),
                                        arguments: item);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                      color: lightRed,
                                    ),
                                    child: const Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                        size: 28,
                                        color: textColorWhite,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Center(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.signal_wifi_connected_no_internet_4,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(
                              "İnternet Yok",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Thanks for help.

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.
Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets. The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a Center widget.
The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  RichText ← Text ← Flexible ← Center ← Row ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Listener ← RawGestureDetector ← ⋯
```

Comment: Can you start your app on your phone in debug mode and update your question with the error in your debug console.

Comment: I updated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, nice that you are trying to make such a nice app! Then you need to clean up your code. Its too much in one script. Try to move every section to its own widget.

Then your error says, that you are using the Flex wrong.

1. Try by removing both of your Flexibles.
2. If its not working replace the first Flexible, which wrapes your Warning Icon-Container, with Expanded and give it a flex like 1. And still remove your second Flexible and Wrap your Center with Expanded and give it a flex like 3. 
   It should look like:

```
 child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Text("Yardıma ihtiyacım var!"),
                ),
                ],
           ),
```

If its not working, send me the new error code and i will try your come by my self.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what causing your problem but `Flexible` needs to be a direct child of the `Row` and this is what's causing the error message you have. Your second `Flexible` is inside a `Center` which is the incorrect usage. You can try swapping these 2 widgets, so instead of

```
                      const Center(
                        child: Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            "Yardıma ihtiyacım var!",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: textColorWhite,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

do

```
                      const Flexible(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Yardıma ihtiyacım var!",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: textColorWhite,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the Top Row inside `Flexible`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It's still the same.

Comment: You could remove top SizedBox as it does not do anything effectively.

Comment: @Rahul -- It would be more helpful, if You would elaborate more in-depth, why Your proposals should work.